# Strange bugs with localStorage with useState react

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I tried to save values of the input with localStorage and i have a strange bugs, it doens't load data from localStorage.

1- I set the data of multiple input with setItem in useEffect in the InputFile.js

```
    useEffect(() => {
    let validateInputs = {
      fullNameValidate: enteredFullNameIsValid,
      phoneValidate: enteredPhoneIsValid,
    };

    setValidation(validateInputs);

    const allData = { fullNameEntered, phoneEntered };
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(allData));
  }, [
    enteredFullNameIsValid,
    enteredPhoneIsValid,
    setValidation,
    fullNameEntered,
    phoneEntered,
  ]);
```

2 - i update the value of the handler in the custom hooks (use-input.js) :

```
const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState({
    enterValidate: "",
  });

    const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue({
      ...enteredValue,
      enterValidate: event.target.value,
    });
  };
```

3- I tried to take the values saved with (in custom hooks, use-input.js):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const saved = localStorage.getItem("data");
    const { fullNameEntered, phoneEntered } = JSON.parse(saved);
    setEnteredValue((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, fullNameEntered, phoneEntered };
    });
  }, []);
```

But it doesn't works!

UPDATE:

here there are the 2 complete files:

1- custom hooks for the inputs

```
    const useInput = (validateValue) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState({
    enterValidate: "",
  });
  const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false);
  const [clickClasses, setClickClasses] = useState(false);

  const valueIsValid = validateValue(enteredValue.enterValidate);
  const hasError = !valueIsValid && isTouched;

  const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue({
      ...enteredValue,
      enterValidate: event.target.value,
    });
  };

  const inputBlurHandler = () => {
    setIsTouched(true);
    setClickClasses(false);
  };
  const inputClickHandler = () => {
    setClickClasses(!clickClasses);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setEnteredValue("");
    setIsTouched(false);
  };

////TAKE STORED DATA////// BUT IT DOESN'T WORK

  useEffect(() => {
    const saved = localStorage.getItem("data");
    const { fullNameEntered, phoneEntered } = JSON.parse(saved);
    setEnteredValue((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, fullNameEntered, phoneEntered };
    });
  }, []);

  console.log(enteredValue);

  return {
    value: enteredValue.enterValidate,
    isValid: valueIsValid,
    hasError,
    valueChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler,
    inputClickHandler,
    click: clickClasses,
    reset,
  };
};

export default useInput;
```

2- Input files

```
    import React, { useEffect } from "react";
    import useInput from "../../../../../hooks/use-input";
    import validateInput from "../../../../../utils/validateInput";
    import {
      WrapperNamePhone,
      LabelNamePhone,
      SpanInputDescription,
      InputStyle,
    } from "../ContactFormInput.style";
    
    export default function FullNamePhoneInput({ setValidation }) {
  //FullName Input
  const {
    value: fullNameEntered,
    isValid: enteredFullNameIsValid,
    hasError: fullNameHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: fullNameChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler: fullNameBlurHandler,
    inputClickHandler: fullNameClickHandler,
    click: fullNameClickClasses,
  } = useInput((value) => {
    const inputValidFullName = {
      value: value,
      maxLength: 20,
      whiteSpace: true,
      allowNumber: false,
      allowStrings: true,
    };

    return validateInput(inputValidFullName);
  });
  //Phone numbers input
  const {
    value: phoneEntered,
    isValid: enteredPhoneIsValid,
    hasError: phoneHasError,
    valueChangeHandler: phoneChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler: phoneBlurHandler,
  } = useInput((value) => {
    const inputValidPhone = {
      value: value,
      maxLength: 15,
      whiteSpace: true,
      allowNumber: true,
      allowStrings: false,
    };

    return validateInput(inputValidPhone);
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    let validateInputs = {
      fullNameValidate: enteredFullNameIsValid,
      phoneValidate: enteredPhoneIsValid,
    };

    setValidation(validateInputs);


//STORE DATA////

    const allData = { fullNameEntered, phoneEntered };
    localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(allData));


  }, [
    enteredFullNameIsValid,
    enteredPhoneIsValid,
    setValidation,
    fullNameEntered,
    phoneEntered,
  ]);

  //FUll NAME
  const borderColorFullName = fullNameHasError ? `rgb(245, 2, 2)` : `#d5d9dc`;

  const clickedColor = fullNameClickClasses ? "#2696e8" : "#a4aeb4";

  //PHONE NUMBERS
  const borderColorPhone = phoneHasError ? `rgb(245, 2, 2)` : `#d5d9dc`;

  return (
    <WrapperNamePhone>
      <LabelNamePhone htmlFor="full-name">
        <SpanInputDescription clickedColor={clickedColor}>
          Full name
        </SpanInputDescription>
        <InputStyle
          type="text"
          name="full-name"
          id="full-name"
          borderColor={borderColorFullName}
          value={fullNameEntered}
          onChange={fullNameChangeHandler}
          onBlur={fullNameBlurHandler}
          onClick={fullNameClickHandler}
        />
        {fullNameHasError && <p> - Enter a valid Full Name</p>}
      </LabelNamePhone>
      <LabelNamePhone htmlFor="phoneNumber">
        <InputStyle
          placeholder="Enter a valid phone number"
          type="text"
          name="phoneNumber"
          borderColor={borderColorPhone}
          value={phoneEntered}
          onChange={phoneChangeHandler}
          onBlur={phoneBlurHandler}
        />
        {phoneHasError && <p> - Enter a valid Phone Number</p>}
      </LabelNamePhone>
    </WrapperNamePhone>
  );
}
```

///////////////////////////
//////////////////////////

Final Update, i don't like this solution but it works!
I've done like this:

-1 I deleted the setKeys from the Input files.

-2 I update the setKeys dinamically in the use-input hooks:

-3 then with useState i update the getItem!

```
    const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState(() => {
    return {
      validateInput: "",
      fullName: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("fullName")) || "",
      phoneNumber: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("phoneNumber")) || "",
      email: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("email")) || "",
      country: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("country")) || "",
      From: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("From")) || "",
      To: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("To")) || "",
    };
  });

      const valueChangeHandler = (event) => {
    setEnteredValue({
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      validateInput: event.target.value,
    });

    localStorage.setItem(event.target.name, JSON.stringify(event.target.value));
  };

*/ Other code for validation, useless in this example */


  return {
    value: enteredValue.validateInput,
    valueName: enteredValue.fullName,
    valuePhone: enteredValue.phoneNumber,
    valueEmail: enteredValue.email,
    valueCountry: enteredValue.country,
    valueFrom: enteredValue.From,
    valueTo: enteredValue.To,
    isValid: valueIsValid,
    hasError,
    valueChangeHandler,
    inputBlurHandler,
    inputClickHandler,
    click: clickClasses,
    reset,
  };
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand; "setEnteredValue" doesn't differentiate between name/phone and it's not clear how you're storing updates of either back to local storage. And the initial state vale will always defer tp the order shown. You may need to provide more details.

Comment: I have update the post, now i think it's more clear what i mean, thank you

Answer (score 1):

I m not sure i have completely understood your problem, however instead of doing all that in useState you could use an effect and set its value based on any dependency or just on component mount like so:

```
const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState({});

useEffect(()=>{
const saved = localStorage.getItem("data");
const { fullNameEntered, phoneEntered } = JSON.parse(saved);
setEnteredValue({
  ...enteredValue,
   fullname:fullNameEntered,
   phone:phoneEntered
})

},[])
```

you can change to add some conditions to ensure its not null before being set etc. but this approach should work in general instead of using a callback in useState.

You can then use the values in the component via the state i.e `enteredValue?.fullname` etc. (?. is optional chaining to prevent undefined errors)